# Querying collections in Oracle BI using TABLE statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, obiee

everyone. I am using Oracle Business Intelligence EE and I was trying to get a table data that has a collection as of varray of varchar. The code is following:

```
 SELECT CODE,
        e.column_value as NAME
 from document t, TABLE(t.name) e
 where e.column_value is not null;
```

The above code works fine in PL/SQL and returns wanted records. However, when I want to use it in Obiee data model, its query builder keeps giving ORA-00907 missing right parenthesis error. If I simply select table `document`  as `select * code, name from document t` then the column that has a collection shows null values.  What can I do in this situation?

**EDIT!** I don't know how this solution is optimal, but query worked after I removed the semicolon ';' at the end of the query.

Comment: What does the last sentence mean? Does it work now (i.e. you solved the problem),  or not?

Comment: Littlefoot, Yes, it worked. The only thing I did was I removed semicolon.

Comment: OK, understood. I'm glad you fixed it.

Comment: Question: Why are you postong SQL? OBI works with modela, not code.

Comment: Chris, I am trying to create a data model via SQL query and use it for a report, that is why I posted a code.